# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'tokenize'

Tags: python, python-2.7, module, virtualenv, nltk

I have `nltk` installed in my `virtualenv`. When I do `pip freeze` , among other packages I can see `nltk==3.2.1`.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and python 2.7. And After activating virtualenv, when I try to import `nltk` from python shell, I get following error.

```
 >>> import nltk
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>   File "/home/kenden/den/codes/myenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/__init__.py", line 128, in <module>
        from nltk.chunk import *   File "/home/kenden/den/codes/myenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/chunk/__init__.py", line 157, in <module>
        from nltk.chunk.api import ChunkParserI   File "/home/kenden/den/codes/myenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/chunk/api.py", line 13, in <module>
        from nltk.parse import ParserI   File "/home/kenden/den/codes/myenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/parse/__init__.py", line 79, in <module>
        from nltk.parse.transitionparser import TransitionParser   File "/home/kenden/den/codes/myenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/parse/transitionparser.py", line 21, in <module>
        from sklearn.datasets import load_svmlight_file   File "/home/kenden/den/codes/myenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
        from .base import clone   File "/home/kenden/den/codes/myenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/base.py", line 11, in <module>
        from .utils.fixes import signature   File "/home/kenden/den/codes/myenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
        from ..externals.joblib import cpu_count   File "/home/kenden/den/codes/myenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/__init__.py", line 127, in <module>
        from .parallel import Parallel   File "/home/kenden/den/codes/myenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/parallel.py", line 30, in <module>
        from .format_stack import format_exc, format_outer_frames   File "/home/kenden/den/codes/myenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/format_stack.py", line 35, in <module>
        generate_tokens = tokenize.tokenize AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'tokenize'
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Try `nltk.download('punkt')`

Comment: I think if it's NLTK > 3.2, using `nltk>=3.2.1` would be more appropriate since most components should try to keep users' space.

Comment: I have downloaded all packages except `panlex lite`. Also when I run `pip install --upgrade nltk` it shows already the latest version.

Comment: did you name your script `nltk.py`? If so call it somehting else, maybe something like `mynltk.py`.

Comment: no, I havn't named any file so.

Comment: do you have a script named `tokenize.py`? The same error might occur.

Comment: Yes I do have. Thanks a lot. It solved my problem. (by renaming it)